# How to position children in a Stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, flutter-positioned

I have a `Stack` containing 2 `Positioned` children widgets, one of them containing a `CircleAvatar` widget and the other a `Column` widget.

The `Column` widget contains two `InkWell` widgets but when I add a position (eg. *"left:10,"*) the widgets `CircleAvatar` and `Column` disappears and I can't figure why.

The code is below:

```
Stack(
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  children: [
    Positioned(
      right: 100,
      child: CircleAvatar(
        maxRadius: 75,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              balance.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 23,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'EGP',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xffa80f14),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      // left:10,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 18,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, 'Recharge');
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 170,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffa80f14),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                    spreadRadius: -2,
                    blurRadius: 6,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Recharge",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              //Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'MyTickets');
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 170,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffa80f14),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                    spreadRadius: -2,
                    blurRadius: 6,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "My Tickets",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Visually:

[image: picture to make it clear]

If I uncomment *"left:10,"* the content of the `Stack` disappears and I get this error instead:

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 588
> pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the CircleAvatar to be in front of the Column, you need to put it at the last position in the list passed to `Stack.children`.

```dart
Stack(
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  children: [
    Positioned(
      left: 10,
      child: Column(
        children: [...],
      ),
    ),
    // --- mind the swapped position of CircleAvatar and Column ---
    Positioned(
      right: 100,
      child: CircleAvatar(...),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Does this answer your question?